# Passing a variable to trigger hide/show panels

Tags: jquery, triggers, hide, show

I have a panel hide/show setup that is triggered from a list item anchor. Works great. The problem is, I also have a dropdown menu in the site navigation that also needs to trigger each panel, from any page on the site. Like say, I have panels (in this order), "Hardware", "Software", "Accessories" on the Products page. So when I'm on the About page, and I click "Software", the expected result is to take me to the Products page and have the "Software" panel open.  Here's my jquery script for the panel:

```
$("ul#product-type li a").click(function() {
$("ul#product-type li").removeClass("selected");
$(this).parent().addClass("selected");
var currentTab = $(this).attr("href");
    $("div.panel").hide();
    $(currentTab).show();
return false; });
```

Dropdown Nav Markup:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="/products/#hardware"><span>Hardware</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/products/#software"><span>Software</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/products/#accessories"><span>accessories</span></a></li>
```

I've tried adding the nav selector to the click function, but that doesn't work. Any ideas or suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Cheers,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` isn't a valid selector, since `$("/products/#hardware")` wouldn't work.  However using the `.hash` property is perfect, as you'll get `$("#hardware")`.  Use it like this:

```
$("ul#product-type li a").click(function() {
  $("ul#product-type li").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
  $("div.panel").hide();
  $(this.hash).show();
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you Nick!  That worked great. my click function now looks like:

$("#nav li ul li a, ul#product-type li a").click(function() {

Do you think there is a way keep the "selected" class working when the #nav link is clicked?  Right now, it just removes the "selected" class from the ul#product-type li and adds it to "nav li ul li".

Comment: @Ryan - I'd change `$("ul#product-type li").removeClass("selected");` to `$("ul#product-type li").not($(this).parents()).removeClass("selected");` to exclude the parent chain if that's what you're after.